# How to raise an exception instead of returning NaN

Tags: ruby, nan

I'm trying to find the place in my code from which a NaN is being generated, and I am thinking that, for that purpose, it would be very helpful to change the general behavior of Ruby to raise an exception when a NaN would otherwise be generated. For example, raise an exception when 0.0/0.0 is attempted instead of returning NaN.

It doesn't appear to be possible, but perhaps someone knows how to do that. EDIT: I take it back, the monkey patching solution below seems to work.

Comment: ruby doesn't have a NaN datatype, actually

Comment: @maxple Well, whatever it is that's shown as "NaN". I don't know if it's actually just a string or a symbol or a bona fide IEEE 754 NaN. There is a Float::NAN but, as I'm sure you know already, there is a range of bit patterns which are interpreted as not-a-number in IEEE 754, so there can't be just one such value. I looked at the Ruby source code, and it looks like Ruby is making use of IEEE 754 NaN, but I can't tell for sure. If you know more about it, I'd be interested to hear.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a bona fide IEEE 754 NaN.  My litmus test is whether `0/0.0 == 0/0.0`. If `true`, it's not IEEE. In Ruby (>=2.2.2 at least), that expression evaluates to `false`.

Comment: @Oregonwhiteoak my bad, spoke too soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can monkey patch `Float#/` using refinement (remember that most operators in Ruby are just methods)

```
module RaiseExceptionOnNaN
  refine Float do
    def /(*)
      super.tap {|result| raise ZeroDivisionError if result.nan?}
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your module/class, use the module

```
class MyClass
  using RaiseExceptionOnNaN

  # Have a try
  0.0 / 0.0
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am giving it a try. Although I had to write the last line of code like this: `Float.send(:prepend, RaiseExceptionOnNaN)` because I got `private method prepend called for Float:Class (NoMethodError)` when I tried it the way it is shown above.

Comment: There is so much awesomeness in this answer. I wish I could upvote it twice.